# How to index ralational Database with solr?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, solr, solrnet

As I explained in my post a few days before I'm programming an ASP MVC3 multi-language website which should contain facetted search, full text search and a distance search. To realize that I've installed solr 3.3 on a Tomcat 7. I'm also successfully integrated a dataimporthandler.

Now I want to index the data from my relational ms sql database. I read the index structure looks like one table containing all the data of one object. That means if I've got a object like a car my schema catains fields like Branding, Color and so on.

1. But what about n-m realtions? Does the index "table" have one column for each relation?
2. And what about multi language items? Should I create one object/row int the index for each language?
3. And should I save just the id of objects in the index or the whole names?
4. And last how to index (query) a Object like on the database image? (I read something about dynamic fields and multiplevalue fields but I'm not sure if it is the solution for my problem)

I've a example of a database design I'm talking about attached.

Thanks for all the answers!!!

[image]

Update:
The people should be able to have different way to search. 
They should have the possibility to search the tbl_text_local.text by full text searching and the miscellaneous are are facettes.
The Result should be a list of objects that match to the search and a list of facetts.

But how should I index the Miscellaneous? Is there a posibility to index them in a form like that:

```
<cattegory name = "cat1">

<Miscellaneous>
name...
</Miscellaneous>

<Miscellaneous>
...
</Miscellaneous>

<Miscellaneous>
...
</Miscellaneous>

</cattegory>


<cattegory name = "cat2">

<Miscellaneous>
</Miscellaneous>

<Miscellaneous>
</Miscellaneous>

<Miscellaneous>
</Miscellaneous>

</cattegory>
```

*People should have a searchfield like:*

**Text input (to search the text)**

Facettes:

**Miscellaneous-Cattegory1**

- Miscellaneous1 (9)
- Miscellaneous2 (39)
- Miscellaneous3 (49)

**Miscellaneous-Cattegory2**

- Miscellaneous5 (59)
- Miscellaneous6 (69)

**Miscellaneous-Cattegory3**

- Miscellaneous7 (7)
- Miscellaneous8 (8)

**Miscellaneous-Cattegory4**

- Miscellaneous9 (19)

Comment: @Richard: this is **not** about relational database design at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single, "best" way to model relationships in Solr. Unlike relational databases, where you design tables by following [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), in Solr the schema design is very much ad-hoc, a function of the searches you will perform on the index. Ask yourself these questions as guidance:

- What are users searching *for*? What is the "result type"? The schema should be designed around this.
- What information do I need to facet?
- What information do I need to include in full-text search?
- What information do I need to use to sort results?
- What information will I search *by*? I.e. what information will I use to filter search results, and how will I use that information?
- What will I process at index-time and what will I process at query-time?

Finally, don't be afraid of duplicating data in the index for specific search purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've started to work on your points and updated my Question on it. But I had some problems on answering your last point...

Comment: @HW90: I'm sorry but the question is getting way too specific of your particular project... Stackoverflow is not a free consulting service.

Comment: +1 for "Finally, don't be afraid of duplicating data in the index for specific search purposes." I spent weeks fighting the old paradigm.